# Can't comment // on codeblocks

Tags: c, linux, codeblocks

I'm using codeblocks to learn C programming.

When I use `/* */` the program works, but when I use `//` the program returns this error.

```
expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘/’ token|
```

here's the main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Ex1

int i;
float p;
char *n;

int main(void)
{
    i = 22;
    p = 70.0;
    n = "Samuel";

    printf("%s %d %.2f", n, i, p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And can we see the codeblocks? And how are you commenting it?

Comment: Can you post a larger part ot the code?

Comment: // is C++, not c. Perhaps you're compiling a .c file, and your compiler is being strict?

Comment: can't i use // in c? so how to comment a line?

Comment: `//` comments were introduced in C99. Configure the IDE to use C99, or better, C2011.

Comment: @Poldie: That should be an answer (it is the answer).

Comment: According to the codeblocks wiki (http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Coding_style#Commenting) you should be able to use //.
What happens when you move the comment into actual code? (so not just your includes before it)

Comment: @Kippie is retuns the same error

Comment: @Poldie No, // is perfectly fine in standard C. If you people only code in obsolete versions of the standard, fine, that's your problem. But don't go preach obsolete standards on SO.

Comment: @Damon No it really shouldn't, since it is incorrect and will get downvoted.

Comment: Codeblocks uses C99 by default as far as i know...are you sure you are using the latest version ?

Comment: @Cygnus: Code::Blocks does not define any standard unless you click either the "ANSI" or another similar option. GCC defaults to `gnu90` when not told anything different. Therefore, double-slash comments aren't allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From wiki:

C++ style line comments start with // and extend to the end of the line. This style of comment originated in BCPL and became valid C syntax in C99; it is not available in the original K&R C nor in ANSI C:

Answer (score 5):

If you use `gcc` compiler, then add `-std=c99` compiler argument. 
It will enables C99 features, like `//` comments.

If you have `-ansi` option, then remove it.

Comment: If gcc, `//` comments are available in the default gnu89 mode, so only the absence of explicitly asking for C89/C90 is necessary. Nevertheless, explicitly asking for C99 or later is good.

Answer (score 4):

Four major versions of the C language exist:

- ISO 9899:2011. The current standard, known as C11. Allows //.
- ISO 9899:1999. An obsolete standard, known as C99. Allows //.
- ISO 9899:1990. An obsolete standard, known as C90, or sometimes C89. Does not allow //.
- Pre-standardization. Known as "K&R C". Does not allow //.

Make sure to use a modern compiler with support for the relevant standard. Today, you should demand that a C compiler at least conforms with C99.

Comment: C90 is sometimes referred to as "ANSI-C" by confused people, because it was standardized in USA 1989, one year before international standardization. But all of the C standards, including C90, are ISO/IEC C. ISO is the international standard institute, IEC is the international electro-technical commission. These supersede national standard institutes. In national publications in USA, and only there, they may be referred to as "ANSI/ISO/IEC 9899:2011" etc, but that doesn't make much sense, since no translation from English to native is needed in USA. Outside USA, ANSI is completely irrelevant.